# struct to ubyte[] or ubyte[] to struct for d language

Tags: d, dmd

How the implementation of the struct in the D language to `ubyte []` or `ubyte []` to the struct, please brothers help answer this question, thank you!

If a struct contains the `string` or `char []` what to do?

For example, such a structure:

```
struct UserLogin 
{ 
    align(1): 
      ushort ClientId; 
      int AccectId; 
      string LoginUid; 
      string LoginPwd; 
}
```

Attention to my application in the socket!

Comment: For real serialization see the existing answers.
Otherwise a reinterpret cast is what you want, something like (cast(ubyte*)var)[0..UserLogin.sizeof]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert the raw data, the suggested idiom is like this:

```
struct_type* s = new struct_type;
ubyte[] ub = cast(ubyte[]) s[0..1];
struct_type* s2 = cast(struct_type*) ub.ptr;
```

This will not handle serialization of strings and pointers, though. You will need to do that manually or with a library.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's anything in the standard library to automatically serialize and deserialize structures to byte streams. `std.stream` does that for a variety of basic types, but not entire structs. Apache Thrift support is on the way. Among 3rd-party solutions, you can have a look at the [Orange](http://www.dsource.org/projects/orange) serialization library.

Comment: I think Orange will make it into phobos.

Answer (score 2):

@Dev Wolf : You have to write serialization/deserialization yourself. Apart from the Orange mentioned by CyberShadow you also have the Thrift protocol implementation :  http://klickverbot.at/code/gsoc/thrift/ . I remember some guys worked on Google Protocol Buffer implementation as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct UserLogin
{
  align(1): 
  ushort ClientId; 
  int AccectId; 
  char[10] LoginUid; 
  char[10] LoginPwd; 
}

UserLogin* readByteToStruct = cast(UserLogin*)ne.data;
```

Will be able to properly take the data...